# Rails soft delete with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a small app where I got a simple user model, and I'm currently trying to add some soft delete functionality (yes, I know there are some gems for this). Works fine for users, however when I delete a user, the associated topic view collapses as it cannot find the deleted user anymore due to the default scope I guess.
Any idea how to get arround this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :topics
 has_many :comments
 default_scope { where(active: true) }
end

def index
 @topics=Topic.all
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  if current_user and current_user.role == "admin"
    @users=User.unscoped.all
     else
      @users=User.all
  end 
end
```

Part of the view (topic.user.name is where it stops working):

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=link_to topic.title, topic %></td>
    <td><%=h topic.description %></td>
    <td><%= topic.user.name %></td>
    <td><%=h topic.created_at.strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S') %></td>
    <td><%=h topic.updated_at.strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S') %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't see `@topics ` defined in your controller code? Can you post that code too?

Comment: Also you want to display all topics(event for those users whose active column is set to false)?

Comment: Added Topics controller's index, though it's very easy indeed.

Comment: User will exist because in soft delete you're just updating active column with false. So my question is why `topic.user.name` is not working? because user is never really deleted/destroyed. You want to show all topics? or only those topics where user is active?

Comment: Yes the point is that for example someone creates a topic, and then two years later this person is deleted, however I don't want to remove a topic with 500+ comments just because the original author left the site.

Comment: I guess topic.user.name is not working because of the default scope that hides the deleted user's name from the view if the user who is currently logged in is not an admin, or not even logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why [`default_scope`](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil) is evil. By now you've realized that having a `default_scope` can lead to a wild goose chase.

You can change *user.rb* to this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_many :comments
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :inactive, -> { where(active: false) } # can be used in future when you want to show a list of deleted user in a report or on admin panel.
end
```

then controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.scoped
    @users = @users.active if current_user && current_user.role != 'admin'
  end
end
```

view will have no problem of your topics#index now:

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=link_to topic.title, topic %></td>
    <td><%=h topic.description %></td>
    <td><%= topic.user.name %></td>
    <td><%=h topic.created_at.strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S') %></td>
    <td><%=h topic.updated_at.strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S') %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Whenever you want to display active users just do: `@users = User.active`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, and leave the associations as it is.

```
<td><%= topic.user.try(:name) %></td>
```

Comment: This can bypass the exception pretty well, however still can't display the corrensponding username.

Comment: because the associated user has been deleted. One work around would be to store username in topics as well.